# Connecting to sql server 2008 database using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I tried connecting using a connection string and get this error: 
"Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0."

here is my code :

```
   SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection(@"C:\PROGRAM FILES\MICROSOFT SQL SERVER\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\TARGIL3.MDF");
        SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter();
        adapt.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand(" INSERT INTO tblEmployee VALUES (@employeeNumber, @employeePrivateName, @employeeFamilyName ,@city, @street, @houseNo, @phoneNumber, @birthDate, @startWorkingDate)", Con);
        adapt.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@employeeNumber", SqlDbType.Char).Value = textBox1.Text;
        adapt.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@employeePrivateName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox2.Text;
        adapt.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@employeeFamilyName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox3.Text;
        adapt.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@city", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox4.Text;
        adapt.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@street", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox5.Text;
        adapt.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@houseNo", SqlDbType.Int).Value = textBox6.Text;
        adapt.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@phoneNumber", SqlDbType.Char).Value = textBox7.Text;
        adapt.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@birthDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(textBox8.Text);
        adapt.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@startWorkingDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(textBox8.Text);


        Con.Open();
        adapt.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Con.Close();
```

Comment: you don't connect to sql server database like that. check this link [SQL Server Connection Strings for ASP.NET Web Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj653752.aspx)

Comment: You should be connecting to the database instance name, not to one of the physical files behind it. It looks like your code is missing the second half of the first line too!

Comment: How to I connect by name than?

Comment: Also check this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring.aspx

Comment: Change your connection string to something like this
`"Data Source=YOURSERVER;Initial Catalog=YourDatabase;UserId=yoursqluseid;Password=yourpassword"`

Comment: Further info on how to formulate your connection string: http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this:

```
string connString = "Data Source=SERVERNAME;Initial Catalog=DATABASENAME; User ID = USERNAME; Password=PASSWORD;Integrated Security=false";
SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection(connString);
```

Answer (score 0):

You connection string is wrong. It should be of this form if you use SQL Server Authentication:

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;
Password=myPassword;
```

Where `myServerAddress` is the IP or host name of the computer running SQL Server. If it's your PC, `localhost` will probably work.

`myUsername` and `myPassword` are the credentials of the user connecting to the server.

If you use Trusted Connection,you connection string should be of this form:

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;
```

You can check more examples here: http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just put a file name in the connection string

```
C:\PROGRAM FILES\MICROSOFT SQL SERVER\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\TARGIL3.MDF
```

Sql Server is a usually a "service", and you talk to the service..........

Now. If you are using "Express" version......then you may have to include the AttachDbFilename parameter.

http://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlconnection/attach-a-database-file-on-connect-to-a-local-sql-server-express-instance-1/

```
Server=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=C:\MyFolder\MyDataFile.mdf;Database=dbname;
Trusted_Connection=Yes;
```

But if you are NOT using "Express", then you should only put info about the Sql Server SERVICE (machine\instancename, etc, etc), and not care about the physical path of the .MDF.

Sql Server is not JET (Access).  With JET, you would only specify the filename.

If you're still having issues, you should post which version of sql server you are using.....do a "select @@version" and report that.